# Add a number above a cell and continuing on in excel (example given)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a formula in excel to add the cell above to the current cell. Then in the cell below, add the current cell and the one above and so on. I am currently doing it manually and it is taking forever. This is how the manual formula goes. I am working in cell A1 and going down. A1 has a number in it.

- =23
- =40+A1
- =63+A2
- =70+A3
- =50+A4

The numbers are sales data and I am looking to create a running total of sales each month. The number before the "A#" is what the sales for the month are.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The overriding issue is that a cell cannot contain both a numerical value and a formula at the same time. The most common workaround is to use another (adjacent) column to find these totals with a formula. This lets you keep the original data intact.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to have your monthly sales data in a single column and the running total next to it. For instance, your data would look like this:

```
A   B
23  23
40  63
63  126
70  196
50  246
```

The formula in `B1` should be `=SUM(A$1:A1)` and then you copy / paste it down as needed. The `$` will lock the first reference at row 1 but the second cell reference will update as it's copied down. For instance, `B5` will automatically have the formula `=SUM(A$1:A5)`.